# Facing a ReferenceError: self is not defined ,when deploying in vercel

Tags: next.js, strapi, vercel, clerk

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/middleware.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.requirePage (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:88:12)
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:48:73
    at async Object.loadComponents (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:48:26)
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /middleware
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:963:15 {
  type: 'Error'
}
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

when deploying in vercel i got this error "Self is not defined".It works fine while `npm run dev` but got an error while deploying

Answer (score 0):

just you need to move your component where you have this error outside pages folder